# Rails Simple Form multi-page single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, simple-form, multipage

I am working on a model with a form (I'm using Simple Form) that has many inputs but is not nested and I'm only working with one model.

I'm looking for the best way to display one question or a couple questions at a time and then once they have answered those continue with the next set until they reach the end and submit. I have looked into Wizards and Multi-page solutions but they seem too advanced for this purpose because it is not a nested form and it is static, forms are not being created dynamically.

I read a suggestion about using javascript to hide different parts all within the same form file but I have not found a good example or tutorial for this strategy.

Let me know your suggestions and any applicable tutorials for simplifying a form for the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a row of tabs accross the top and as you click each tab a different `div` is selected to show, and other `div`s are hidden.

There is a very simple tutorial at w3schools.com including a "try it" button that shows it in action.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp